# Authentication to neo4j fails

Tags: java, http, authentication, servlets, neo4j

I want to access the neo4j database.    I tried the following:

```
    ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher");
    ChallengeResponse ch = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC);
    ch.setRawValue("bmVvNGo6bmVvNGo=");
    resource.setChallengeResponse(ch);
    Representation re = resource.post(query);
```

however, I get an error:

```
    Unauthorized (401) - Unauthorized
```

What am I doing wrong in the authentication?

Comment: Why don't you use a proper username / password API ?

Comment: Did you set the initial password separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `neo4j/neo4j` please change the password in the server first and then use that.